# Unable to get certain elements from RSS feed

Tags: ruby, rss

I'm having trouble with the default ruby rss parser, specifically getting a couple elements from the Rogan podcast feed:

> http://joeroganexp.joerogan.libsynpro.com/rss

```
open(url) do |rss|
  feed = RSS::Parser.parse(rss)
```

Now when I look at `feed`, I can't find the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:cc="http://web.resource.org/cc/" xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
```

And strangely enough I can get all the channel data except the last one (itunes:type):

```
    <itunes:type>episodic</itunes:type>
```

Comment: You might also want to use a library with direct support for iTunes RSS, e.g. https://github.com/feedjira/feedjira

Comment: I was trying to avoid gems like feedjira since sometimes people add their own custom data to feeds that I'd want to capture as well.

Comment: Okay, but for the record, Feedjira does let you configure custom tags in both the feed and its items. (e.g. Feedjira::Feed.add_common_feed_element "image", as: :the_image`)